# Multiple controllers bad for performance?

Tags: scrollmagic

Does it have an impact on performance to use multiple controllers for the same container?

I'm asking because I'm using several layout modules in my project. I'd like to know if it is easier to have separate controllers and scenes for every module.

Answer (score -1):

the performance is not linked to number of the controllers directly

more controllers for further functionality.

Users Controller where users can create new accounts. 
admin interface where you can edit the resources with higher privileges.

is depend on the context of your application you put in one controller if the context is the same

one controller for every table in your database that users can access. But this is really only a very crude measurement.

Comment: I don't think you and OP are talking about the same thing... ScrollMagic has nothing to do with databases or users.